# deprecation warning in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a script running scikit Naive Bayes classification, that I wrote on a linux machine. when I transport it to a windows machine, I get a deprecation warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Implicitly casting between incompatible kinds...

in the linux version I have numpy version 1.6.1
and in windows numpy version is 1.7.1rc1.

It throws the warning when casting a list of floats to a 2d array.
Should I ignore the warning? Does it have to do with the change in numpy version?

The casting seems to work ok in both machines...

Thanks

Comment: Ignoring deprecation warnings is asking for trouble later... They are there for a reason, and that is they will most likely become an error eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should of course update your code so that the warning goes away. Maybe by explicitly creating a Numpy array from the list.

I suppose with casting you mean some automatic conversion like:

```
array([1., 2, 3]) * [3, 4, 5]
```

Responsible seems to be the following pull request, that was merged relatively recently. The best explanation is in file `test_ufunc.py`.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/451/files

Comment: wouldn't I get the warning anyway when I cast it myself?

Comment: Constructing a Numpy array is not casting. However it is possible that the Numpy constructor complains about something else.

Comment: The point is the *implicit* cast. This is probably due to operations like `integer_arr += float`, where `integer_array + float` is a float type, which gets then implicitly cast due to the in-place operation.